# Pandas pivot_table fails with columns and margin

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm getting a `KeyError: "... not in index"` while using pivot_table of pandas.
Here is sample code:

```py
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two'], ['A','A','B','B']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second', 'third'])
values = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
df = pd.DataFrame(values.T, index=index, columns = ['0', '1'])

# here comes the pivot_table, this one works, it has 'colums'
df.pivot_table(index = ['first', 'second'],  columns = 'third', aggfunc = 'sum')

#this one works, it has 'margins'
df.pivot_table(index = ['first', 'second'],  aggfunc = 'sum', margins=True)

#this one fails, it has both 'columns' and 'margins'
df.pivot_table(index = ['first', 'second'],  columns = 'third', aggfunc = 'sum', margins=True)
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) 
> ... 
> KeyError: "['first' 'second'] not in index"

Somehow columns and margins are not compatible.

Comment: looks buggy - as a workaround, `df.reset_index()` before the `.pivot_table(...)` seems to work

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you. reset_index turns the Multindex into a set of columns. So, it seems like this functionality works with columns but doesn't work with index

Answer (score 1):

As Asish [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441897/pandas-pivot-table-fails-with-columns-and-margin#comment115699377_65441897), performing a `reset_index()` before calling `.pivot_table` will do the work.

The problem was raised in pandas GitHub Issues and one can follow all the updates [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38691).